# Google Sheets nested IFERROR / VLOOKUP doesn't return correct error value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that return the value in column based on value on a different sheet. The formula works in general, the problem is that it returns "FALSE" instead of "?" when there's an error such as no value to look up.

It's not a terrible problem, but it bothers me that i don't understand what the issue here is. I tried asking GPT but it just says that everything is working a-okay.

Kudos for any suggestions to the formula:

```
=if(C3 = "A"; iferror(vlookup(A3; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-1; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-2; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-3; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-4; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-5; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); "?")))))); 
if(C3 = "B"; iferror(vlookup(A3; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-1; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-2; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-3; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-4; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-5; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); "?"))))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a little difficult to see what's going on because of all the parenthesis, but technically it's working as written. If/Else statements in google sheets work like so: `if(condition, true_expression, false_expression)` (basically if the condition evaluates to `true` it'll spit out the `true_expression`, otherwise it'll spit out the `false_expression`). Technically speaking you only really need to specify the `true_expression`, if you do something like `if(condition, true_expression)`, Google Sheets will automatically spit out `FALSE` if the condition evaluates to false (even though you didn't include a `false_expression`). I believe that's what's happening in your case. If you modify your formula to something like the below I think you'll get what you want:

```
=if(C3 = "A"; iferror(vlookup(A3; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-1; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-2; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-3; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-4; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-5; Ex!$A:$C; 3; FALSE); "?")))))); 
if(C3 = "B"; iferror(vlookup(A3; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-1; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-2; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-3; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-4; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); 
iferror(vlookup(A3-5; Ex!$E:$G; 3; FALSE); "?")))))),"?"))
```

Basically it was just returning `FALSE` because the initial conditions were not evaluating to true (ie `C3` did not equal `"A"` or `"B"`. That being said, I might recommend changing all the nested `iferror` statements to `if(iserror())`. Technically it works out the same, but I personally think it reads more logically given what you are doing even if you end up with more parenthesis, but that's all personal choice.